# Convert elements of list to a list of consecutive elements in an efficient way

Tags: python, list

I have a base list `[1,4,10]` which needs to be converted to a list having consecutive elements of each element in the base list in an efficient way

Examples:

- If I need 2 consecutive numbers then `[1,4,10]` will be `[1,2,4,5,10,11]`.
- If 3 consecutive numbers then `[1,4,10]` will be `[1,2,3,4,5,6,10,11,12]`.

Comment: and did you try writing anything yourself? How did that go?

Comment: what should the answer be for [1,2,3] and 2 connectives?

Comment: @Sam `[1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4]` logically

Answer (score 1):

```
arr=[1,4,10]
con=3
[r + i for r in arr for i in range(con)]
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10, 11, 12]
```

Comment: How is this answer specific to python 3.x?

Comment: sorry is int -- i confused myself with change of range in python3 compared to range and xrange in python 2 -- in this case it doesnt make a difference. I'll edit the answer

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way. [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) removes the need for explicit nested loops.

```
from itertools import chain

def consecutiver(lst, n=3):
    return list(chain.from_iterable(range(i, i+n) for i in lst))

res = consecutiver([1, 4, 10], 2)
# [1, 2, 4, 5, 10, 11]

res2 = consecutiver([1, 4, 10], 3)
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10, 11, 12]
```

Comment: The `chain.from_iterable` also accepts generators (so you can drop the `[]`). Not sure how this affects efficiency though. Nice answer.

Comment: Seems overly complicated. Why are you making the `range` a list for instance? You can do this with no imports whatsoever... Since you've already given a working solution - then I had: `return [el for n in base for el in range(n, n+2)]` which'd be `return [el for val in lst for el in range(val, val + n)]`

Comment: Thanks for both your suggestions. Personally, I don't think there should be some kind of anti-import preference. If you look at the code for `itertools.chain`, it is a fairly trivial construct.

Comment: Sure... I love `itertools.chain`... you just don't need it.... you also don't need the extra `()`s around the chain as you've got no other arguments (and can't provide any, anyway, so that'll at least make it look a little nicer)

Comment: @jpp The only thing I have against imports for trivial tasks is that it does not promote effort. You get a sense that you do not have to learn the logic behind coding but simply to know which library to use.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis sometimes I find `chain` far more readable as to what it's doing. The elements it's going to add can be shown on the left (thus (to me at least) a bit more obvious) rather than in a nested for-loop comp - which can for some still take a bit of deciphering...

Comment: @JonClements True, but going through the process of deciphering is the only way to learn to how to code. Imo at least. Could be wrong ofc. `[n for sub in [range(x, x+req) for x in lst] for n in sub]` for president xD

Comment: I'm glad others have come up with the nested `for` loops.. In my opinion, this is a good example of exactly when to use `chain.from_iterable`.. Agree, it's not great for learning purposes, I've added some explanation too, which might help OP.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a one liner, assuming the list is x and the number of 'consecutives' is c:

```
reduce(lambda a, b: a + b, map(lambda x: range(x, x+c), x))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [1,4,10]
k = 3 #no of consecutive 
x=[range(b,b+k) for b in a]
output = [m for d in x for m in d]
```

Comment: why use numpy instead of just `range` here?